# How to slice image in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native. Could someone point me in the right direction here? I'm trying to accomplish the following: given some image, I want to slice it up so that each slice can be touched individually, and the slice is saved as an image.

#### Original image

[image]

#### Slices

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is one image. Each square is a `<View>` with `<Image source={IMAGE} style={{ resizeMode:'stretch' width:origImageWidth, height:origImageHeight, top:CALC_ME, left:CALC_ME }}/>` but each image is offset to make a part of it show.